# Application stopped unexpectedly at launch

Tags: android, overlay, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

I've run this on a device and on the emulator. The app stops unexpectedly on both.

I have not a clue what is wrong currently.

It uses Google API Maps I compiled with Google Api 7.

I followed this tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html
(made some alterations clearly)

I did use the correct API Key That the final apk is signed with

[This is the source](http://poppoob.com/uploads/0627b940de.zip)(If you compile it shouldn't work as it is unsigned)

[This is the compiled signed apk](http://poppoob.com/uploads/f69c29d9d3.apk)

Log

```
03-21 00:30:38.912: INFO/ActivityManager(54): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.chris.stryker.worldly/.com.poppoob.WorldlyMap }
03-21 00:30:39.173: INFO/ActivityManager(54): Start proc com.chris.stryker.worldly for activity com.chris.stryker.worldly/.com.poppoob.WorldlyMap: pid=287 uid=10031 gids={3003, 1015}
03-21 00:30:39.532: DEBUG/ddm-heap(287): Got feature list request
03-21 00:30:40.185: WARN/dalvikvm(287): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/chris/stryker/worldly/com/poppoob/WorldlyMap; (17)
03-21 00:30:40.193: WARN/dalvikvm(287): Link of class 'Lcom/chris/stryker/worldly/com/poppoob/WorldlyMap;' failed
03-21 00:30:40.205: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(287): Shutting down VM
03-21 00:30:40.223: WARN/dalvikvm(287): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-21 00:30:40.223: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.chris.stryker.worldly/com.chris.stryker.worldly.com.poppoob.WorldlyMap}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.chris.stryker.worldly.com.poppoob.WorldlyMap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@45a13938
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.chris.stryker.worldly.com.poppoob.WorldlyMap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@45a13938
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
03-21 00:30:40.252: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     ... 11 more
03-21 00:30:40.300: INFO/Process(54): Sending signal. PID: 287 SIG: 3
03-21 00:30:40.312: INFO/dalvikvm(287): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-21 00:30:40.396: INFO/dalvikvm(287): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-21 00:30:49.002: WARN/ActivityManager(54): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
03-21 00:30:49.685: WARN/ActivityManager(54): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{458ab6d0 com.chris.stryker.worldly/.com.poppoob.WorldlyMap}
```

Comment: would you mind posting some log indicating the failure?

Comment: Why did it work when you ran in emulator? This is the reason I posted the apk. Ill go run through the emulator and get a log for you, will take a while though brb

Answer (score 1):

Fix your manifest by adding/moving

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

into *application*.

Answer (score 0):

The key line is:

> 03-21 00:30:40.185:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(287): Unable to resolve
>   superclass of
>   Lcom/chris/stryker/worldly/com/poppoob/WorldlyMap;

This probably means you have loaded your APK into an emulator AVD that lacks the Google APIs.

Comment: No actually I'm pretty sure I did!

Comment: Oh and I went back to check and yeah I did, Ran it again! Same output

Comment: OK. What does `com.chris.stryker.worldly.com.poppoob.WorldlyMap` inherit from? Whatever it is, you don't have it.